# Access Octopus Deploy's System Variable in SQL script

Tags: octopus-deploy

If I use the "Execute SQL Script Template" the following SQL works:

```
Print N'#{MyVariable}'
```

This prints out "Hello World" if I set MyVariable to "Hello World" in the variables of the project.

However

```
Print N'#{Octopus.Deployment.Id}'
```

Prints out exactly that. How do I get it to print out Octopus system level variables?

Note that this question is **not** specific to getting the Deployment Id. Just how to get Octopus variables in my SQL script in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to an old (2018) version of Octopus. Upgrading to the latest version would solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce this. Are you executing the step template directly from the library page? If that's the case, a number of those system variables will not be populated because they are only present in the context of a deployment.

If you are running the step in a deployment and getting that behavior, can you contact support@octopus.com with the details of your configuration?

Comment: This was due to an old (2018) version of Octopus. Upgrading to the latest version solved the issue